# Recognize dates placed randomly within string

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a way to recognize date stamps within a string in an Excel-cell, using VBA, and then determine which is closest to todays date. The cell is used for all sorts of comments.

The date stamps will always be looking like this:

```
dd.MM.YYYY or d.M.YYYY
```

There could be any number of stamps like this within the same cell.

**Example**

Lets say that cell B5 has the following contents:

*12.3.2015 I have done this and this. 20.11.2015 Done something more.*

I would now like to recognize the two date stamps, and find out how many days separates today from the freshest one.

That last part i know can be sorted out with something like `DateDiff("d", y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value, Date)`, although that wouldn't work in this example, being that the cell contains a string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the date always located in the beginning of the string? Because then you could just use the Left Method on the cell, and extract the first 10 or so characters.

Comment: No, thats part of the problem, the dates could be located anywhere within the string.

Comment: By your example the format is either `d.m.yyyy` or `dd.m.yyyy`, confer `.3.`.

Comment: True, thats a good point.

Comment: For all practical reasons an `InStr(i,str,".20")` loop shall suffice.

Comment: That's assuming all dates are from 2000 and onwards.

Comment: Try taking a look at the comments on this site: http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/08/17/extract-dates-from-text/

They have various methods of doing what you want.

Comment: Are you familiar with Regular Expressions?  Sounds like a great fit here...

Comment: @jdl134679 No, I sadly am not. But yeah, that looks promising. I'll read a little. Thanks.

Comment: Google for "regex find date" and you'll get tons of basic examples (most of which will probably work).  Then do a search for "vba regex" and you'll get the script needed to use it within VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regular Expressions, they're made for this sort of thing.  I won't get into extreme details on how all the RegEx stuff works, the basic gist of RegEx is that there's a string of characters, where each character means something specific about the search you want it to perform.  For example, say *Find all strings that consists of a group of numbers between 1-12 followed by a (pick your date delimiters), followed by one or more numbers that is within 1 and 31...* etc.)

RegExLib.com usually has some decent solutions for common problems such as this.  Here's one we can try: http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=932 (but we'll remove the leading ^ and trailing #):

```
([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})
```

> Validate american date formats: mm/dd/yyyy or m/d/yy or m.d.yyyy with separators: . - / Valid dates only! m (1-12)/ d (1-31)/ y (0..)

Then we whip up some VBA for it.  I prefer late binding this so I don't need an added reference just for one regex check:

```
Public Function GetDelimitedDatesInString(StringIn As String) As String
  Dim ret As String
  Dim matches As Object
  Dim regex As Object
  Dim pattern As String
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

  pattern = "([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})"

  Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

  regex.pattern = pattern
  regex.Global = True


  Set matches = regex.Execute(StringIn)

  For i = 0 To matches.Count - 1
    ret = ret & ";" & matches(i).Value
  Next i

  If Len(ret) Then ret = Mid(ret, 2) 'trim leading delim

  GetDelimitedDatesInString = ret

End Function
```

Comment: Seems promising, but at which point is StringIn being evaluated? I've testet it slightly, and after correcting a typo in "CreateOjbect" it works, but not returning any results.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, changed the Execute line to `Set matches = regex.Execute(StringIn)`

Comment: Great. But i suppose there's something I'm not getting. How would you go about retrieving the result after finishing the evaluation of a string? Is the result also a string?

Comment: There, I tested this one, seems to work fine.  Took two pieces out of the pattern and switched some return related code around, ought to give you a semicolon delimited list of found values now.  Answer editing accordingly (re-paste the whole function)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Got it to work after some fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub e(s As String)
Dim myarr() As String, mydate(50)
j = 0
datestr1 = "##.#.####*"
datestr2 = "##.##.####*"
For i = 1 To Len(s)
    If Mid(s, i) Like datestr1 Or Mid(s, i) Like datestr2 Then
        myarr = Split(Mid(s, i), ".")
        dateday = myarr(0)
        datemonth = myarr(1)
        dateyear = Left(myarr(2), 4)
        mydate(j) = DateSerial(dateyear, datemonth, dateday)
        MsgBox mydate(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This is not the expected output but could get you going, the point is if the string matches what you're looking for you create an array with the date being in the first three array items.